# different colors for each records in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I just want to add different colors for each records within foreach loop.I tried to add but I couldn't make it. Given below is my function.

```
public function service()
{
    $result = Order::getService();
    $out = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $out[] = array(
            'id' => $row['orderID'],
            'class'=>'event-special',
            'title' => $row['customer_name'].' - '.$row['order_number'],
            'url' => URL::to('/').'/customer/'.$row['customerID'].'/order/'.$row['orderID'].'/edit',
            'start' => strtotime($row['start_date']) . '000',
            'end' => strtotime($row['end_date']) .'000'
        );
    }
    return json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'result' => $out));
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create yourself a set of `event-special` css classes i.e. `event-special1`, `event-special2` ......

And then amend the code to add a number to your existing class

```
public function service()
{
    $result = Order::getService();
    $out = array();
    $color = 1;
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $out[] = array(
            'id' => $row['orderID'],
            'class'=>'event-special' . $color,
            'title' => $row['customer_name'].' - '.$row['order_number'],
            'url' => URL::to('/').'/customer/'.$row['customerID'].'/order/'.$row['orderID'].'/edit',
            'start' => strtotime($row['start_date']) . '000',
            'end' => strtotime($row['end_date']) .'000'
        );
       $color++;
    }
    return json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'result' => $out));
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but no colors.  :(   Actually in event-special class I mentioned the backgroud-color: #ffe6ff;

Comment: Are you sure you created a new set of css classes with the right names?

Comment: No I didn't. How to create that??

Comment: In the sites .css file

Comment: Well you cannot expect a css class to add anything to the party, if you dont code that css class eg `.event-special1 { background-color: #123456}`

Comment: Actually i'll be having 1000's of records. In that case how can many classes i can create in css file like .event-special1000???

Comment: @cathy123 The example is good and follows exactly what you asked for.  Would it be more sensible that you want x different colors and then loop over them repeatedly? Adding a counter reset(if($i > 5) { $i = 1; } at the beginning of the foreach would solve that.